# Minimum Number of Generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A subset $S$ is said to generate a group $G$ if every element of $G$ can be written as a finite product of elements of $S$ and their inverses. Let $d(G)$ be the minimum number of generators of $G$.

Prove that the quaternion group of order 8, $Q_8$ satisfies $d(Q_8)=2$ and that the alternating group $A_4$ satisfies $d(A_4)=2$.

My approach: Well $Q_8$ is generated by $(i,k), (j,k)$ or $(i,j)$. So this is easy to see. I am not quite sure about $A_4$.

Comment: What have you tried? Since both groups are not commutative, they can't have $d(G)=1$. So all you need to do is find two elements which geenerate each group.

Answer (score 2):

$Q_8$ is not cyclic, so we need at least two elements, consider $i$ and $j$, see that generates.

$A_4$ is also not cyclic, prove it is generated by $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,2,4)$.

Comment: Yes thank you so much!

Comment: Hint for the second part: $(123)$ and $(124)$ along with their inverses and the identity permutation are allready $5$ elements, if you can find at least two more elements generated by these you are done. Why? the subgroup generated by $(123)$ and $124$ would have at least $7$ elements, by Lagrange it has to be the whole group.

Comment: Why is it that if a group is not cyclic, then you need at least two elements to generate the group?

Comment: that's basically the definition of a group being cyclic. There are many reasons why the groups in question are not cyclic, one of them is as Thomas points out that they are not abelian, while all cyclic subgroups are abelian.

Answer (score 0):

Hints

- To prove $d(G) \le k$, find $k$ elements of $G$ that generate $G$.
- To prove $d(G) \ge k$, prove that any set of $k-1$ elements will not generate $G$. In particular, when $k=2$, what does this statement translate to?